# How do I obtain this SQL output using a POWERSHELL script

Tags: sql, powershell, windows-7

I have a set of SQL instructions and I want a precise output using a powershell script. I'm a total ignorant regarding PS scripts and SQL. Could someone help me on how to do it?

\\\\\\\\\\\ SQL CODE \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME
    SELECT @table_name = 'Godzilla.Jobs'

    DECLARE 
          @object_name SYSNAME
        , @object_id INT

    SELECT 
          @object_name = '[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + ']'
        , @object_id = o.[object_id]
    FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE s.name + '.' + o.name = @table_name
        AND o.[type] = 'U'
        AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0


    Etc....
```

\\\\\\\\\ THE OUTPUT I WANT \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
        CREATE TABLE [Godzilla].[Jobs]
        (
                 [JobId] BIGINT NOT NULL
               , [MacAddressWifi] NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
               , [SerialNumber] NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
               , [TrpId] NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
               , [SniffsPackage] NVARCHAR(4000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
               , [DecryptPackage] NVARCHAR(4000) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
               , [StatusID] INT NOT NULL
               , [DateInsert] DATETIME NOT NULL
               , [DateUpdate] DATETIME NULL
               , [EstimatedTime] BIGINT NULL
               , [Priority] BIGINT NULL
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in "PowerShell" way of running a SQL query. If you have the [SQL Server tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/powershell/sql-server-powershell?view=sql-server-2017) installed, you'll get an [Invoke-SqlCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2017) cmdlet.

Because PowerShell is built on .NET, you can use the ADO.NET API to run your queries.